# Looking for a Statistical Modelling Technique for a Credibility Scoring Model

Tags: machine-learning

I’m in the process of developing a model that assigns a credibility score to fatigue reports within an organization. Employees can report feeling “tired” an unlimited number of times throughout the year, and the goal of my model is to assess the credibility of these reports.

The model should consider several factors, including:

- The historical pattern of reporting (e.g., if an employee consistently reports fatigue on specific days like Fridays or Mondays).
- The frequency of fatigue reports within a specified timeframe (e.g., the past month).
- The nature of the employee’s duties immediately before and after each fatigue report.

I’m currently contemplating which statistical modelling techniques would be most suitable for this task. Two approaches that I’m considering are:

1. Conducting a descriptive analysis, assigning weights to past behaviors, and computing a score based on these weights.
2. Developing a Bayesian model to calculate the probability of a fatigue report being genuine, given that it has been reported by a particular employee.

What could be the best way to tackle this problem? Is there any state-of-the-art modelling technique that can be used?